# Need an adjective for the word "question"

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

What do you call a question that needs to be answered in the affirmative for a larger question to be answered in the affirmative?

I'm writing an introduction in this way:

This article attempts to answer the following question: <question specified>.

> To answer this question, we also need to answer the ________ question: <subsidiary question specified>

What will fill the blank appropriately? "Subsidiary" seems weak and inelegant.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Perhaps *subordinate, secondary,  supplementary*!

Comment: Rewrite.  For example: To investigate this, we must first determine what the most economical solution would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider *preliminary*:

> coming before and usually forming a necessary prelude to something else

<sub>(source: [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/preliminary))</sub>

It's quite commonly used in (scientific) articles.